# Highlight specific user with custom field value

Tags: customization, loop, users

I'm working on a Wordpress project with some friends from school. But there's a problem with highlighting a user on the website. The idea is to create a 'User of the month' thing.

In the user section of the Wordpress admin panel we've created a custom field to select if a user is user of the month.

For posts we used a normal loop with an array to filter the posts on some pages. But how to do this for a user that is 'User of the month'?

We would like to show the profile picture and the full name.

Thanks!

Comment: Please include the code by which you created the custom field. Also, try to be more specific about what you want to show and on which pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can get users by user meta, using the WP_User_Query class.  There's a great explanation at https://tommcfarlin.com/get-user-by-meta-data/